# How to handle large payload xml attacks when using gsoap library for parsing xml request in C?

Tags: c++, c, xml, large-data, gsoap

I recently came across a scenario where during the parsing of a xml attribute, it's getting stuck during the parsing since the input is very large.
The input is intentionally made large, so need to handle this scenario.

```
SOAP_FMAC1 int SOAP_FMAC2 soap_element_end_in(struct soap *soap, const char *tag){
...
n = sizeof(soap->tag);
while ((c = soap_get(soap)) > 32)
{
   if (n > 1)
   {
     *s++ = (char)c;
     n--;
   }
}
...
}
```

The above snippet is a part of the function which is trying to read through the large input and getting stuck. It is defined in the gsoap libraries `stdsoap2.cpp` file.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/gsoap2/

It was possible to handle the scenario by adding a counter variable and reading the input xml until that counter variable was less than of the value of predefine macro `SOAP_TAGLEN (1024)` which is for the `maximum length of XML element tag/attribute name or host/path name + 1`.

But that would cause modification to the gsoap library code itself.
What I want to know is what is the recommended way of handling these bad payloads when using gsoap library ?
Is there any specific function that can validate the input or will setting any specific member of the soap variable handle these conditions ?
Currently haven't been able to understand why the large input check is not explicitly added in the library defined function itself.
Any insights of handling these bad payloads and how to use the gsoap library for these scenarios would be helpful.

Comment: There's no general way to handle abusive input. You just have to either absorb/discard it or give up

Comment: Can you please suggest some way how to discard it when the input xml size is large ?

Comment: Noone is perfect, it's clearly a flaw of code written by human being and should be reported

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your quoted code truncates the tag read to at most `sizeof(soap->tag) - 1` bytes, but the code by itself shouldn't get stuck in an endless loop, even, if the input is huge. That's because the code calls `soap_get()` repeatedly. I assume, that `soap_get()` will return either 0 or -1 on end of input, which then terminates the `while()` loop. It's quite possible, that there is an endless loop triggered by abusive input elsewhere in the code, but not here.

Comment: I have tried the scenario after adding the counter logic, it was breaking out of the loop.
But without the counter logic , the machine where this scenario was tested was not able to handle this request properly, say went into an error state.

Comment: There are settings in gsoap that limit the size of the XML input accepted. Setting a limit below a few MB or even smaller should be reasonable. Such limits are typical for production employments.

Comment: Is there any reference link where I can explore how to set such limits ? I'm haven't been able to  figure out how to do it. So can you please also share a small example how to do it using gsoap library ?